# how to make a jquery/css scales effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to make a scales in my website with a balancing effect. It should go up and down, up and down and so on.. Take a look at the example below[image]

Is there something in jquery or css that can make this kind effect on a object?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably CSS Transform.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

It has the rotate property which you can set on the top piece and change accordingly get your desired effects.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotate

Answer (score 1):

[i made a js fiddle that should answer your question.](https://jsfiddle.net/r8ufqbo2/78/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var leftSize = $('#left-box').height() * $('#left-box').width();
  var rightSize = $('#right-box').height() * $('#right-box').width();
  if (rightSize >= leftSize) {
    var rotatePercent = 1 - (leftSize / rightSize);
    var Deg = (rotatePercent * 20);
    $('#scale-top').css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + Deg + 'deg)',
    })
  } else if (leftSize > rightSize) {
    var rotatePercent = 1 - (rightSize / leftSize);
    var Deg = (rotatePercent * 20);
    $('#scale-top').css({
        transform: 'rotate(-' + Deg + 'deg)',
    })
  } else if (leftSize === rightSize ) {
    $('#scale-top').css({
        transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
    })
  }
});
```

it pretty much calculates the area of each div, divides the size of the smaller one from the bigger one, subtracts that answer from 1 to get the amount it should rotate, multiplies that number by 20 and uses that number for the degrees that it rotates.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work, but I understand what you made. Thanks for your work!

Answer (score 1):

Only CSS version:

The keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes scale-top{
 from {transform: rotate(-20deg);}
 to{transform: rotate(20deg);}
}
```

in the large rectangle div:

```
animation: scale-top 5s infinite alternate-reverse;
```

Testing in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/4cykoudp/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't say it in the question but my plan was to let it wobble for like two times and than let it stand straight. I don't think that, that is possible with css only, isn't it?

Comment: try this:animation: scale-top 5s 2 alternate-reverse;